# Convert discrete sum to principal integral

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematics

I'm studying IQHE beginning with Laughlin's famous gauge argument. I referred to his Nobel Lecture, in which he mentioned a paper that enlightened him. It is Phys.Rev.B.23.5632(1981) which talked about the effect of a delta impurity. In this paper, there is a discrete sum
$$
1=2\pi\lambda \sum_{np} \frac{|\psi _{np}(0)|^2}{E_{\alpha}-n-pv}
$$
Because $pv$ is much smaller than $n$ and $E$ he converts the discrete sum over $p$ to a principal integral plus the contribution of p near singular points.

I would to know how to make this conversion. Is there any general method to convert a discrete sum to a principle integral?

Here is the principal integral result in the paper:

[image]

Equation (2) he mentioned is just the equation I wrote down above.

Comment: Hi. Could you also please, post the integral? Thank you.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack I post it below. Thanks for your interests.